# Need help quering a table based on a time range

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to query a table based on a time range based for day, and  it doesn't seem to be working. Its return 0 rows. Below is the SQL query I am using.

I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly here..

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!

```
SELECT * FROM checkout_page 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(checkout_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%I:%S')
BETWEEN '2015-8-23 11:00:00 ' AND '2015-8-23 15:00:00'
```

Here is a sample date from my table

```
2015-08-23 20:00:21
```

Comment: try using `2015-08-23 11:00:00` instead of `2015-8-23 11:00:00` in the `where` clause.

Comment: Also, no need to use DATE_FORMAT.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. ChipsLetten helped me resolve the issue by using the CAST() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use `DATE_FORMAT` on the `checkout_date` but could/should instead explicitly `CAST` the two values in your `WHERE`clause.

```
SELECT * FROM checkout_page 
WHERE checkout_date BETWEEN '2015-8-23 11:00:00' 
AND '2015-8-23 15:00:00'
```

Using `CAST`:

```
SELECT * FROM checkout_page 
WHERE checkout_date BETWEEN CAST('2015-8-23 11:00:00' AS datetime) 
AND CAST('2015-8-23 15:00:00' AS datetime)
```

Comment: Got it. Never even knew about the CAST() function until now. Thank you the explination

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM checkout_page 
WHERE hour(checkout_date) BETWEEN 11 and 14
```

selects all records having a time value between '11:00:00' and '14:59:59'

Comment: @jueregen d . Thanks a lot for the response, but I needed the rows to be returned form a specific date also .. not just time